# pycharm intelisense issue with builtin method

Tags: python, pycharm

I use Pycharm 2020, already try to restart and invalidate cache, adding virtual environment and Pycharm still not able to show builtin method from Python interpreter

here is my sample code, when i type `contents = response.` Pycharm not showing read() method, however if I type manually there is no error and I can run my code.

[image]

How i can fix this? I have try many thing when searching in SO, including restart, create new project, adding venv, restart Pycharm etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below link.

[Pycharm Troubleshhoting might help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html#troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm makes completion suggestions based on the type inferred for some particular variable or attribute.

Type of `response` could be checked by `View - Type Info`, inferred type is `Any` and that means that actual type is unknown.

It could be easily fixed using type hints:

```
from http.client import HTTPResponse

res = urlopen("http://google.com")  # type: HTTPResponse
```

or

`res: HTTPResponse = urlopen("http://google.com")`